# Bootstrap tooltip on exceeding textbox maxlength

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a textbox which allows a maximum of 40 characters to be entered.When the user tries to enter the 41th character ,I need to display the bootstrap tooltip (not on focus or hover).I am struggling with it and not able to do it.Please Help. I have also created the JsFiddle for that

http://jsfiddle.net/Vijay4225/gjLusomk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#textBox').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $('#textBox').val().length;
    if(text_length ==40) {
    $('#textBox').attr('title','you cannot enter more than 40 characters');
    $('input[rel="txtTooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tooltip `trigger` to `manual`, i.e `data-trigger="manual"` and then show the tooltip manually by `tooltip('show')`. Besides that, I think `keydown` is a better event for this task - the tooltip should appear as soon as the user hits the keybord, not when the user has stopped typing. I would also suggest that you implement some logic to prevent the tooltip from blinking or reappear if it already is shown.

```
$('#textBox').keydown(function() {
   if ($(this).val().length>=40) {
     if ($(this).data('warning')) return;
     $(this).attr('title','you cannot enter more than 40 characters');
     $(this).tooltip('show');
     $(this).data('warning', true);
   } else {
       if ($(this).data('warning')) {
          $(this).tooltip('hide');       
          $(this).data('warning', false);                  
       }    
   }
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hb3bmo50/**